# Diluted Explanation of file.path() function in R

Tags: r, function, filepath

new to stack overflow here. I'm learning R as I have an ambition to learn statistical modeling via programming. This is my second-ever language I'm learning (1st was SQL)

I'm doing the tutorials, and researched on google, but I cannot truly get a diluted, non-technical explanation as to what the file.path() function does. In swirl, it gives me a demo to do file.path("folder1","folder2") and the output is [1] folder1/folder2 , but what's the context of that? I tried it on my own computer and didn't see any new folders in that directory I was working in. Thoughts? The only thing it says is that filepath() creates folders that are independent of the operating system it's working on. Well cool, but where are these folders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't create the folders, it creates file paths which are independent of the operating system implementation. To create these folders, use

```
dir.create("folder1/folder2", recursive = TRUE)
file.exists("folder1/folder2")
# [1] TRUE
```

If you expected the code to be ran on someone else's computer, you would want to create the path like so:

```
path_to_folder <- file.path("folder1", "folder2")
# On most computers, `path_to_folder` would be "folder1/folder2".
dir.create(path_to_folder, recursive = TRUE)
file.exists(path_to_folder)
```

On Windows, filepaths are frequently separated with `\` (represented as `\\` in R). A path such as `folder1\\folder2` would fail on Linux, so we wouldn't want to use that directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `?file.path()`, it says -

> Construct the path to a file from components in a platform-independent
>   way.

So with that, let's say I have a requirement of traversing file systems that can be run across OS - Windows, Linux etc.

`file.path()` is a good application for building platform independent file paths -

```
file.path('/Users/vk','Desktop', fsep=.Platform$file.sep)
```

which will output -

```
[1] "/Users/vk/Desktop"
```

This is especially useful when you have multiple files that you want to read across folders - it gives you the programmatic flexibility to construct these file paths and work your way across. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I get it now Vivek! So essentially you do the file.path() function as like a reference. And when you want to do something to many files in those directories, or just those directories, you would reference that file.path() function!

Comment: @MichaelVetri yes!